# How can I share my life event on Facebook to my friends' news feeds?

Tags: facebook

I edited my graduation date in my Facebook profile to become today. I made sure that my school in my profile has a privacy setting of "public". However, I only saw this life event "Graduated from University XXX" shown up in my timeline; but my friends said that they cannot see anything in their news feed.

Is there anything I can do to share this life event to my friends?